# When I use Pycharm run a python file(in fact it is my first use), always report error, for example:

Tags: python, selenium, pycharm, geckodriver

environment: mac osx 10.11.2, python 2.7, selenium-3.0.0.b2, firefox 45

I just create a python file and run , code is

```
/**
from selenium import webdriver
import time
dr = webdriver.Firefox()
time.sleep(5)
print 'Browser will be closed'
dr.quit()
print 'Browser is close'
**/
```

then report error:

> File
>   "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium-3.0.0.b2-py2.7.egg/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py",
>   line 65, in **init**
>       self.service.start()
>
> File
>   "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium-3.0.0.b2-py2.7.egg/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py",
>   line 71, in start
>       os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message)
>
> selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'geckodriver'
>   executable needs to be in PATH.

I have got a file geckodriver,maybe I know this error because of I didn't set path,but, I don't know how to set this PATH in Mac?

Comment: So did you search for 'mac add to path' on google yet? This is question isn't about Python, or PyCharm, or Selenium, really.

Comment: I have did in commond line like :

export PATH$PATH:/Users/MYNAME/geckodriver

but it doesn't work, always report error , why? please help me ,thanks!